# Unable To Show Multiline Textbox text with new line in Label

Tags: c#, asp.net

If i enter below text in my multi line textbox

```
Nitin
Kumar
Shukla
```

then i got this result

```
Nitin Kumar Shukla
```

but i want result same as i write in my multi line textbox

Here is my aspx page code

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ttt" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="hjhj" onclick="btn_Click" />
   <asp:Label ID="lll" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

here is my cs page code

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lll.Text = ttt.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
lll.Text = ttt.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```